# I didn't understand the solution to the integration $\displaystyle\int_b^0 \left[ \frac{mb}{2k} \left( \frac{x}{b-x} \right) \right] ^\frac{1}{2}dx$

Tags: integration

How did $b^3$ appear ? It has something to do with division by $b$ ?

[image]

**EDITED**:

Doge Chan give me the answer to the questions above. But, I still don't understand the final answer. Does it did a substitution of $sin^2\theta$
by $x$ \ $b$ ? If it was made, whre is the $x$  in the final equation ? I tried to make the steps and did not reach the answer

Comment: $dx = d\left(\frac{bx}{b}\right)= b d \left(\frac{x}{b}\right)$ so you pick up an extra $b$ that becomes $b^2$ when it's moved into the square root.

Comment: Have you learned integration by substitution?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari I learned it many years ago, now I am a little rusty

Comment: I guess that's why you are getting problems.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Yes, Iknow. I lost the handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to do the explicit substitution, instead of losing oneself in keeping track of factors.

If you substitute $x=by$, the integral becomes
$$
\int_1^0 \left[ \frac{mb}{2k} \left( \frac{by}{b-by} \right) \right] ^{1/2}b\,dy
$$
*Assuming* $b>0$, you can push the factor $b$ in the square root and pull the constant factor outside the integral to get
$$
\left(\frac{mb^3}{2k}\right)^{\!1/2}\int_1^0 \left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^{\!1/2}\,dy
$$
Now you can see the $b^3$, don't you?

By the way, the integral must be negative, when $b>0$. The substitution $\sqrt{y}=\sin\theta$ yields (without the factor that can be reinstated at the end)
$$
\int_{\pi/2}^0 2\sin^2\theta\,d\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
because an antiderivative is $\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta$.